# Retrofit query parameter without "="

Tags: android, retrofit

Maybe there is a question have already been asked, but i coulnd't find it
How to implement this query in Retrofit
`https://i.picsum.photos/id/733/200/300.jpg?grayscale`
it will be like:

```
   Call<Post> getBlurGrayscale(@Query("grayscale") ??);
```

How to make query just `blurscale` without "=" and how to add ".jpg" and the end, if the API will not automatically add .jpg?
P.S. I try to use Retrofit to access [Lorem Picsum](https://picsum.photos)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [the `@QueryName` annotation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/QueryName.html). For example:

```
Call<Post> getBlur(@QueryName String query);
```

And then you'd call `foo.getBlur("grayscale")` to produce a url ending with `?grayscale`.

If you were working in Kotlin, you could add a method to your interface to avoid having to pass in `"grayscale"` every time:

```
fun getBlur(@QueryName query: String): Call<Post>

fun getBlurGrayscale(): Call<Post> = getBlur("grayscale")
```